# Power BI - How to make grouping when data is from direct query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, directquery

I have a set of data with this range
0-10,
11-20,
21-30, and
exceed 30.
My data was loaded to power BI using direct query.

I add column from selection in transform data. I was able to auto generate the range
[image]

This is the power query of that column:

> = Table.AddColumn(TAPS_masterData, "Range", each let rangeSize = 10, offset = 0, inclusive = false, rangeIndex =
> Number.RoundDown(([PostingAge] - offset) / rangeSize) in
> Text.From(rangeIndex * rangeSize + offset, "en-US") & "-" &
> Text.From((rangeIndex + 1) * rangeSize + offset - (if inclusive then 1
> else 0), "en-US"), type text)

But when i want to apply the changes, it shows below error:
This step results in a query that is not supported in DirectQuery mode. Switch all tables to Import mode.

Answer (score 0):

Your M code as written works fine

You can go to Power BI Desktop, go to Model view-->Advanced and change the storage mode from DirectQuery to Import

[image]